# Suggest a JMS provider ( for Java platform)

Tags: java, jms

What is the most reliable open source JMS provider ? Any good/bad experience with gearman or Apache ActiveMQ ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123817/which-jms-implementation-do-you-use

Answer (score 3):

I've had very good experiences with ActiveMQ, reasons being:

- very stable,
- light memory footprint,
- easy to deploy and use,
- good documentation,
- ready-to-use enterprise integration patterns via [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

Another goody, while not a common use case but still nice to know: it's fairly simple to *embed* ActiveMQ into your own application as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have only experimented with JMS (i.e. no production use) but found apacheMQ to be pretty good.  The documentation is good.

I've also seen openJMS http://openjms.sourceforge.net/ but have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Messaging / HornetQ: http://jboss.org/hornetq/

http://www.c2b2.co.uk/iPoint/ipoint?SelectedPage=69&110ArticleID=17 (from 2008, though)