# is there any light weight JMS API available

Tags: java, jms

I would like to know if there is any open source light-weight JMS API which can be embedded right in to my web application

Comment: Do you mean a lightweight implementation of the JMS API?  The API is the API, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

- ActiveMQ
- Qpid
- RabitMQ

Answer (score 0):

Any Java-based implementation will most probably satisfy your needs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123817/which-jms-implementation-do-you-use) for some options (or just a [Google search](http://www.google.com.hk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=JMS+java+implementations)).

**In order to make it "lightweight", be sure to turn off persistence and just stick to pure in-memory mode.**

**Disclaimer**: turning off persistance will mean that you will lose all your messages when JVM exits. However, as you are looking for a lightweight solution, this should not be an issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to embed the JVM broker in the applications' JVM. This way the JMS broker would start and stop with your application.

For example for ActiveMQ check the following links:

- [List item](http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-deploy-the-broker-inside-my-jvm-or-appserver.html)
- [example](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)