# A diagram / table about message oriented middleware

Tags: zeromq, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv

Would you guys know a diagram or dable that would give a short & concise but nevertheless complete and relatively up-to-date view of the existing protocols, and their specifics ? (namely : ZeroMQ, Rendez-Vous, EMS, ... All of them! :) ).

Comment: there ain't no such thing as a free lunch

Comment: @Schildmeijer: there is even more than that. Just look at free Wifi, free Software, free Hugs.

Comment: I can help with some of the RV and EMS details if you can provide more details about the specifics you are after.

Answer (score 0):

This one is about open source solutions only : http://blog.x-aeon.com/2013/04/10/a-quick-message-queue-benchmark-activemq-rabbitmq-hornetq-qpid-apollo/

No love for the commercial ones !

Answer (score 0):

Message oriented middleware is a big topic, there are probably more than 50-100 different implementations around. And unfortunately everyone putting together a list has an agenda (like presenting his product or his favourite in the best light). To simplify your search, however, it might help to ask yourself these questions:

- JMS or not ? (EMS yes, Rendezvous no)
- Brokerless ? (ZeroMQ yes, no on the others)
- Free or commercial ?

And once you know more browse through some blogs, for example: https://bravenewgeek.com/dissecting-message-queues/, http://supercoderz.in/amqp-zeromq-jms-tibco-rv-and-so-on-which-messaging-system-to-use/ or checkout [Which JMS implementation do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123817/which-jms-implementation-do-you-use) - my agenda ;-)