# What is the workflow to get live data updates from NodeJS/MongoDB API?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I need to fetch live data in Android App from a NodeJS/MongoDB API. For exemple, I have a list of tasks on the Android screen (fetched from the API). Then one of this documents (tasks) have changed in the MongoDB, the Android screen needs to update the data on the screen once this data have been changed on the server. 
Can anyone help with some workflow? I am not looking for code. Ideias (Arquitecture/Libs) only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this in two way.**

1. Use silent push notification.

   - When **data change** in server then server send **push notification**
     to app.
   - App receive notification Then app get call **API** to update **Data**.
2. Your app sends a request(s) to server **periodically** (After some
   **interval of time)**

Reference link for same: [link1](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-automatically-refresh-data-after-some-fixed-time-on-Android-from-MySQL-server), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048754/efficient-design-for-a-auto-refresh-mobile-app)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out recently that Mongo is launching [MongoDB Mobile] (https://www.mongodb.com/products/mobile). It's in beta but with many interesting features coming. No more need to make turnarounds to make data sync between mobile and the remote server database. 
According to the page, MongoDB Stitch Mobile Sync is coming soon, and it will ensure that data is kept up to date across phones and all other clients in real time.
Another awesome feature that's coming is Offline cache data with auto sync when the connection is back online.